# How to get id from URL in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I am trying to get 'id' from URL in order to delete that specific selected product. I have used `$this->uri->segment(3)` but its not getting any value from URL. Although i can see the 'product_id' in my URL.

If i used `$this->url->segment(2)` it gives me the second value form URL, but i am unable to get product Id.
Following is my code. Kindly guide me.

**VIEW**

```
echo "<a href='delete_controller?product_id=$product_id'>";
echo $name;
echo "</a>";
```

The following URL is generating when i click on $name.

```
http://localhost/designs2/index.php/products_controller/delete_controller?product_id=70
```

**Controller**

```
public function delete_controller()
    {
        echo $product_id =$this->uri->segment(3);           
        echo "Taha";
        $this->load->view('delete_confirmation');
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if you have to pass the value you should enter url like this

```
localhost/yoururl/index.php/products_controller/delete_controller/70
```

and in controller function you can read like this

```
function delete_controller( $product_id = NULL ) {
  echo $product_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i removed `?product_id=` from <a> tag, and it gave me the perfect URL.

Answer (score 23):

Check the below code hope that you get your parameter

```
echo $this->uri->segment('3');
```

Comment: this is old way and it's not good practice to use uri because in this case you bount it on second or thired segment. but @agha's way is greate.

Answer (score 6):

```
$product_id = $this->input->get('id', TRUE);
echo $product_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

View page

```
  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>products_controller/delete_controller/<?php echo $product_id;?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a>
```

controller page

```
  function delete_controller( $product_id) {

         echo $product_id;
         //add your logic

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using the CodeIgniter URI routing wrong:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html

Basically if you had a Products_controller with a method called `delete($id)` and the url you created was of the form `http://localhost/designs2/index.php/products_controller/delete/4`, the delete function would receive the **`$id`** as a parameter.

Using what you have there I think you can get the id by using `$this->input->get('product_id);`

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter you can't pass parameters in the url as you are doing in core php.So remove the "?" and "product_id" and simply pass the id.If you want more security you can encrypt the id and pass it.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but this worked for me

```
  $data_id = $this->input->get('name_of_field');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$CI =& get_instance();

if($CI->input->get('id'){
    $id = $CI->input->get('id');

}
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain your thoughts and process, instead of just showing code. Will probably result in helping more people :)

Answer (score 0):

`n` is your last sagment of you url

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(n);
```