# url strings in codeigniter are giving me a blank page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and I want to use url strings in codeigniter. I set to true in config.php the following :

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

I have a controller and if I access it like this

http://site/bla/partners

it will take me to the partners page. In the controller page I defined a function like this:

```
public function export()
{
$this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

And than I put in the url the following:

`http://site/bla/partners/export?id=123&cat=abc`

but this leads me to a blank page. I would want to take me to the partners page where I can get the 2 strings with GET method. The question is: why the second link is taking me to a blank page but not to the partners page?

Comment: paste the code of form..

Comment: you can use $this->input->get('id'); and $this->input->get('cat');

Comment: it still gives me a blank page

Comment: i think this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180115/how-to-get-id-from-url-in-codeigniter

Comment: Do you have `export` argument in `partners` method?