# When page loads i need access variable from query string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have controller in codeigniter that name is **Product**. When I access product controller, I am passing **cateid** variable in URL as query string parameter and getting on product controller.

I have created two methods in controller with names **index** and **productajax** . When I click on product link then controller index method executes. I need to use **cateid** variable value from URL query string in **productajax** method when page is initially loaded or controller **index** method being called.

```
class Product
{
     public function index()
     {
        $cateid= $this->input->get('cateid'):
        $this->load->view('product'):
     }

     public function productajax()
     {
        // I need to get cateid from index function
     }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180115/how-to-get-id-from-url-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You can do it by creating a public or private variable `$cate_id` in class and when `index` loads then 
assign `$cate_id` variable in your `index` method and when you access `productajax` you can get cat id in `productajax` by using `$this->cat_id`*

Your controller should be like this :

```
// Product class 
class Product extends CI_Controller
{
     public $cate_id;
     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
     }

     public function index()
     {
        $cateid = $this->input->get('cateid'):
        $this->cate_id = $cateid;
        $this->load->view('produxt');
     }

    public function productajax()
    {
        echo $this->cate_id;
    }
}
```

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php